# Python anywhere modules not accessible outside main directory

Tags: python, pip, pythonanywhere

In my attempts to create a web app with python anywhere I have discovered that my preferred module web.py is not preinstalled like other modules such as flask. Upon looking through some forums I came to the understanding that installation would occur in the following fashion in the hash console:

```
pip install --user web.py
```

It was however to my surprise that apparently:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): web.py in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

Upon running the a python 2.7 shell in the main directory (if that is what is actually happening when clicking "New 2.7 Shell") I successfully imported 'web', however when running an identical 'import web' outside of the main directory in /site/run.py I was unsuccesful... Might someone inform me as to what is necessary to correct this problem?

Comment: how are you running the import web outside of the main directory?

Comment: could there be a file or module called web/web.py that's interfering with the system-wide web.py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I apologize for my stupidity... It turns out that pythonanywhere defaults to python 3.x and seeing as web.py is a 2.x module, it was unsuccessful. I can only hope that perhaps this post will help some equally unassuming individual such as myself in the future.

Comment: PythonAnywhere dev here -- I'm a bit confused by that.  On the command line, `pip`, `python`, etc all default to 2.7.  For websites, the Python version used is the one you specify when you create them.  Where did you see something that suggested that the default was 3.x?

Comment: Ah, wait -- I think I know what you're referring to -- was it specifically when you used the "Save and run" button (labelled ">>>") in the editor?  That is indeed 3.4.  There are some hints on how to change that here: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/SaveAndRunPythonVersion